# How long will it take when people say 马上?

Tags: meaning

If someone say `马上`, how long will it take?

2 min? 10 min?

> 马上，汉语词汇，拼音是mǎ shàng，意思是立即。作时间副词，表示时间很短的意思。

马上https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%A9%AC%E4%B8%8A/80352

Comment: It's probably like "real quick" in English. No specific time period.

Comment: "Right away", "just a minute"...

Comment: For some people, especially bureaucrats, it could be days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is like *"in a sec"* in English.

It depends on the speaker, sometimes it's few minutes but like if you are waiting for your girlfriend to put on her makeup, 马上 may mean an hour.

Comment: Could be longer. My friend called his newly met girlfriend and got "马上" as the answer. As it turned out, she never showed - never in his lifetime :)

Answer (score 2):

马上 means immediately.

But just like in English, it really depends on who you're talking to.

Answer (score 0):

As long as immediately in English ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another perspective: which one is more sooner? 即刻，馬上。I would say 即刻.